# Visual Studio 2010 Professional

Tags: windows-xp

I need the product key for Visual Studio 2010 Professional. I have downloaded and used it for sometime and now it requires the product key.
Thanks

Comment: So is it pirated ? Thats not a good practice you know ..

Comment: lol.. thats crime

Comment: Or it was a trial version in which case you can go to [Microsoft.com/visualstudio](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/buy) where you can even get "Visual Studio 2012".

Comment: Requesting pirated key for MS product

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about piracy

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft Visual studio 2010 is not the newest version of VS anymore. The newest version is 2012 and a product key can be bought here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/subscriptions/hh442902.aspx

If you need to use the 2010 version, it seems that you can buy it here:

[http://www.amazon.com/Visual-Studio-2010-Professional-Version/dp/B0038KTO8S](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0038KTO8S)

**Edit:**

If you do not necessarily need the full capabilities of the professional edition, you can get the so called *express* editon for free:

http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/downloads#d-2010-express